# Typo3 Workspace Preview "Not available in the requested language"

Tags: typo3, preview, workspace

When generating a workspace preview-link on a page where the first language is hidden, you will get "page is not available in the requested" language, anybody knows how to automaticly fallback to an active language? This is not a normal behaviour, testet it in another installation, where it works.

Comment: Can you provide more information first like the TYPO3 version you're working on please?

Comment: My guess is that you have to check where `config.sys_language_uid` is set to. If it points out to the `disabled` language it might cause the described issues.

Comment: I'm using Typo3 6.2.9.

Comment: Well even if config.sys_language_uid is set to the disabled language, i still want to automaticly jump to an available language when opening/generating a preview-link. Possible?

Comment: So that is what I say. You might do not refer to a disabled language.